# ScrollBar GridView

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

Tenho alguns GridView no meu projeto, porém alguns possuem muitas colunas e todas são necessárias, gostaria de colocar um scrollbar horizontal no grid, porém além do scrollbar, gostaria de colocar uma seta, para navegar nas colunas, facilitando para o usuário visualizar as informações, além de esteticamente ser bem apresentado. Porém não sei como fazer, alguém sabe o nome desta propriedade, e como posso fazer ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para colocar a `scrollbar` você pode colocar o `GridView` dentro de um `div` com as propriedades `width` e `overflow`, assim: `<div style="overflow-x:auto;width:1000px"><GridView></div>`

Comment: Já as setas, você vai precisar usar elementos (imagens por exemplo) com `position` `absolute` para ficar posicionado onde você quer que apareçam. Depois, ao clicar nos elementos, você precisa mudar, em `javascript`, a propriedade `scrollLeft` do `div`

Comment: O Scrollbar deu certo, preciso saber como se faz para colocar as setas e navegar no GridView.